# Bootstrap button with vertical position effect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to add a position effect on :active state on my bootstrap buttons. Unfortunately, the IE does not render the effect properly. Please use this site and compare the effect between Chrome/Firefox and IE 10/11:

```
  http://jsfiddle.net/stebir/f0nw6kp2/2/
```

If I click on the button, I expect a smooth top transition (which works like a charm in Chrome and Firefox). But IE shifts the label "Button" slightly to right. It's a very subtle effect, but nevertheless it's annoying...

Do you have any idea to prevent this in IE?
Regards, Steven

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/stebir/f0nw6kp2/2/
```

Comment: Link for the lazy: http://jsfiddle.net/stebir/f0nw6kp2/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is default functionality in IE... but there are a couple of ways around it.

1. Use an anchor instead of a button.

`<a id="myBtn" class="btn btn-warning">Button</a>`

2. Use a `span` with `posistion: relative` to keep the text in place.

`<button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-warning"><span>Submit</span></button>`

`button > span { position:relative }`

http://jsfiddle.net/pv01x0ud/

Comment: Thank's! That helped. Anyhow, it's stupid to use an extra span for the button label. Damn IE... :-(